# I can't run Hitleap Viewer.exe on Linux Ubuntu OVH VPS

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, vnc, wine

I'm trying to run this app on Linux VPS. I have tried many methods but I couldn't do it.

First method:

1. Install a Graphic VNC-desktop.
2. Install Wine
3. Log-in and execute the app.

This method didn't work because after a few hours the VNC desktop went down and the app did too.
Why? I think it is because of the app. One day I left the desktop online without the app, and the desktop worked correctly and never went down.

Second Method:

1. I connect to the server via SSH x11 PuTTY connection
2. Install Wine
3. Run the app

This method doesn't work because I can't close the PuTTY windows and keep running the app. I tried to use the app "Screen" for this and so I did this:

1. I connect to the server via SSH x11 PuTTY connection
2. Install Wine
3. Install Screen
4. Run Screen
5. Run the app
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (to minimize the Screen session)
7. Close the PuTTY windows

But still it doesn't work because,
when I close the PuTTY windows, the graphic application closes too.

I need some help. Can you please suggest another way to do this?

Comment: You have to keep the SSH connection open. Closing PuTTY closes the connection.

Comment: I tried that, but after a few minutes appears this error: Putty Network Error: Software caused connection abort

Comment: Sounds like host breaks the connection because it's inactive (you don't issue any commands). Try to enable keepalives in PuTTY (*Connection* -> *Seconds between keepalives*).

Comment: Tried, now appears the same error but after a few hours.
In putty appears all the time the same error when the app is running: http://pastebin.com/SsaZs1RC

Comment: It may be a Wine issue. Try running the app on a local system and see if the same problem appears.

Comment: After 24 hours on local machine is working correctly :S
EDIT: appears an error a lot of times "hitleap viewer.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close", but the app didn't close, I think this is the problem and is caused because of Wine, what can i do? any other option to run this app correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command:

```
nohup "processname" &
```

Or use utilities like screen or tmux

Comment: The OP already mentioned he tried using `screen`.

Comment: I've mentioned other alternatives, other than screen. Beside that, your contribution to solve OP problem is?